# Are inaccessible types allowed as template arguments?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a template class that carries some important metadata:

```cpp
template <typename T> 
struct Metadata {
  static const int ImportantInformation;
};
```

And I have a class that uses a private inner class to do some work:

```cpp
class WorkDoer {
  class Private;

public:
  WorkDoer();
};
```

The private inner class inherits from `Metadata`:

```cpp
class WorkDoer::Private : public Metadata<Private> {};
```

The `ImportantInformation` constant is not automatically defined by the compiler so this needs to be in some compilation unit at top-level scope or linking will fail:

```cpp
template<> const int Metadata<WorkDoer::Private>::ImportantInformation = 0;
```

The above statement compiles under visual studio but clang complains that `'Private' is a private member of WorkDoer`. Which compiler is behaving correctly and how can I work around this issue?

Comment: Are you sure ImportantInformation needs to be initialized outside the class?   It compiles for me (C++17) when I `template <typename T> 
struct Metadata {
  static const int ImportantInformation = 0;
};`   https://onlinegdb.com/Sy2uspn4H

Comment: @JerryJeremiah in this example it does not need to be initialized outside the class.  But in my code, the `Metadata` struct has some (general) functions and other (type-specific) data in it so I would like to avoid specializing the whole thing for every class that uses it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t need that out-of-class definition, because this one will do:

```
template<class T> const int Metadata::ImportantInformation=…;
```

Like any other template declaration, this typically goes in a header.

What you have is an explicit **specialization** of `Metadata::ImportantInformation`.  It appears that this context *should* [suppress access checking](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec#6), but neither Clang nor GCC agree.  (Several variations on this theme reveal a distressing amount of implementation divergence.)

Comment: Unfortunately the purpose of "metadata" in this case is to identify a type so explicit specialization is a must.  Your final paragraph and link to the standard answers my question, so I'm accepting this answer.